# Gradle failing to resolve PrimeFaces theme dependency: peer not authenticated

Tags: ssl, gradle, primefaces

I have a Gradle Java project in which I'm using JSF with PrimeFaces.
In order to change it's theme, I added the required dependency in my `build.gradle` file, which most important parts are configured as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes  'Implementation-Title': 'Arch Project', 
                    'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {    
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()

    maven { url 'https://repository.primefaces.org' }
    maven { url 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public' }
}

configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
}

dependencies {

    /* Cryptography API for BCrypt algorithm. */
    compile 'de.svenkubiak:jBCrypt:0.4'

    /* Primefaces. */
    compile 'org.primefaces:primefaces:5.3'

    /* Primefaces pepper grinder theme. */
    compile 'org.primefaces.themes:pepper-grinder:1.0.10'

    ... another few dependencies
}
```

However, when I run `gradle build` on the console I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\bruno.gasparotto\git\archproject\archproject>gradle build
:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not resolve org.primefaces.themes:pepper-grinder:1.0.10.
  Required by:
      :archproject:1.0
   > Could not HEAD 'https://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/pepper-grinder/1.0.10/pepper-grinder-1.0.10.pom'.
      > peer not authenticated
```

**What I've tried and didn't work so far:**

- Changed the dependency from `pepper-grinder`  to `all-themes`.
- Replaced `https` with `http` on PrimeFaces repo configuration in my `build.gradle` file.

**Also, it's important to mention that:**

- The url `https://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/pepper-grinder/1.0.10/pepper-grinder-1.0.10.pom` is available if I try to access it through the browser.
- I am **NOT** behind a proxy.
- If I remove the `pepper-grinder` dependency, it works just fine.
- The same setup used to work more than year ago, so I believe something new is happening.

Any ideas?
Thanks is advance.

Comment: Dit plain http seriously not work? Same error? That is next to impossible. Tried enable ssl debugging? Might just be that the java-sdk does not by default trust the issuer of the PrimeFaces server certificate

Comment: what java version do you have? I had the same problem with `1.8.0_72-b15` it was solved after updating to `1.8.0_121-b13`

Comment: @Kukeltje, it didn't work, which surprised me as well, I left it with `http` anyway, but there is might be a reason as the following:
@SlavaGornostal, I had the JDK `jdk-8u91`, then I updated to `1.8.0_121-b13` then it worked. Please post your comment as an answer so it become more visible to the others in the future. Thanks.